# Excel: comparing names in two different sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have two excel sheets with about 500 rows each. Worksheet A has a name column E) and worksheet B has two name columns for small and large names(H&I). I want to create a loop that goes through and compares these columns and should it find a match paste this match onto a new worksheet.

Further clarification:

On worksheet B the two name columns are akin to Cigna and Cigna Co for example so they are not always the same name repeated, and on Worksheet A the name may be Cigna, so they are not always exact though. But the name of Worksheet A must match 1 or both names on Worksheet B.

Comment: Why not just do this with worksheet formulas. Some `countif()` formulas would go a long long way here. Do all three columns need to contain the name for it to be a "match" or just if the name is any of the columns more than once? Your question is a little light on details.

Comment: @ JNevill On worksheet B the two name columns are akin to Cigna and Cigna Co for example so they are not always the same name repeated, and on Worksheet A the name may be Cigna, so they are not always exact though. But the name of Worksheet A must match 1 or both names on Worksheet B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this is an easy loop and record, then see if anything from the first sheet is on the second.

Not sure what your small and large names situation is, so I checked both columns

In you VBA IDE go to the tools menu and selecte references. Select "Microstoft ActiveX data objects 2.8 Library.  This will be used for the recordset.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lRowOut As Long

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Activate

    Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")

    'Add fields to your recordset for storing data.
    With rs
        .Fields.Append "Row", adInteger
        .Fields.Append "Name", adChar, 25
        .Open
    End With

    'Loop through and record the name
    lRow = 1
    Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.count

        rs.AddNew
        rs.Fields("Row").Value = lRow
        rs.Fields("Name").Value = ws.Range("E" & lRow).Value
        rs.Update

        lRow = lRow + 1
        ws.Range("A" & lRow).Activate
    Loop

    If rs.EOF = False Then
        rs.MoveFirst
    End If

    'Switch to the second worksheet
    Set ws = Nothing
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    ws.Activate

    'Loop through and see if anything on this sheet was on the first sheet.
    lRow = 1
    lRowOut = 1
    Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.count

        'Check if the column H name was recorded from the first sheet
        rs.Filter = ""
        rs.Filter = "Name='" & ws.Range("H" & lRow).Value & "'"
        If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then
            rs.Filter = ""
            rs.Filter = "Name='" & ws.Range("I" & lRow).Value & "'"
            If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
                'It has a date, delete the current row
                ws2.Range("A" & lRowOut).Value = rs.Fields("Name").Value
                lRowOut = lRowOut + 1
            End If
        ElseIf rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
            'It has a date, delete the current row
            ws2.Range("A" & lRowOut).Value = rs.Fields("Name").Value
            lRowOut = lRowOut + 1
        End If

        lRow = lRow + 1
        ws.Range("A" & lRow).Activate
    Loop
End Sub
```

If you want to look for a part of the name as you say in your comment, you can use a like.  Change the filter lines to something like this.

```
rs.Filter = "Name LIKE '%" & ws.Range("I" & lRow).Value & "%'"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Doing this with formulas, instead of VBA, I would stick a formula in A1 of your new workbook like the following. Assuming that your "Worksheet A" is in Book1 on Sheet1 and your H and I columns from "Worksheet B" are Book2 on Sheet1:

```
=if(countif([Book2]Sheet1!H:I, [Book1]Sheet1!E1)>1, [Book1]Sheet1!A1, "")
```

This says "If, in my columns H and I in Sheet1 of Book2 there is at last one match on the name from Cell E1 in Sheet1 of Book1, then grab the name from Cell E1 on Sheet1 of Book1"

This will leave a good number of blanks, but at that point you can just filter or sort them out.

If the requirements are more complicated than that, like any match across any of three columns, then you can just add the results of multiple `CountIf()` formulas and test them for > 1, or do a single `Countif()` for each column and then union the results, sort/filter, and Bob's your uncle.

If this is going to be something you do often, then it may be worth investing in  the VBA route as that will take the little bit of manual work out of it.